# Running same script with different input variables using batch command

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, batch-processing

I would like to run a script called 'myscript' using the batch command:

```
j = batch('myscript')
```

My script has a function in the beginning so:

```
function myscript(input)
...
end
```

Is it somehow possible to run batch files with different input parameters for my function? I know that there are matlabpool, parfor etc commands, but it is unfortunately not working for me.

Comment: You just call the function directly, j = myscript(someinput)

Comment: But then I can't submit it as a job, so that I can run more scripts in parallel on different cores.

Comment: Then, check [How do I call MATLAB from the DOS prompt?](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-16B8X/?solution=1-16B8X)

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I would like to run the batch command (http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/distcomp/batch.html) in Matlab, so that I can use parallel computing. Unfortunately, I can't find a way how to change variables in the function...

Comment: This might clear things up a bit: technically, Matlab "functions" and "scripts" are not the same thing, and can behave differently. A script is a file with a simple sequence of commands that are run in the context where it is called. A function is a file that defines a top-level function, with input and output arguments, that runs in its own workspace when called. Because it says "function" at the top, What you've got here is a function, and *not* a script. Reread the doco with that in mind.

Comment: And then, to change variables in the batches, add those variables to the input variable list of your function, and you can pass args in to the `batch` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you have to use is indicated in the documentation of [`batch()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/batch.html):

```
j = batch(fcn,N,{x1, ..., xn})
```

and in your case

```
j = batch(fcn, 1, {input})
```

Alternatively, you can check [How do I call MATLAB from the DOS prompt?](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-16B8X/?solution=1-16B8X)

Comment: How would it look like for my function without any output?
j= batch(myscript,{input})?
If I try that I get the following error:
Too many output arguments.

Comment: @C.Colden Do you still get that error if you leave out the `j=`? Basically you are telling the computer that you want an output to fill `j`.